# Why is my model changing when I switch between Object and Edit mode?

Tags: modeling

The model is fine in *object mode*:

[image]

Then, the model's vertices change in *edit mode*:

[image]

Even when I change the mode back to *object mode*,
the vertices of the model are still changed.

[image]

How can I fix it ?

Comment: and I also try `object mode` to `scrulpt mode`, everything go ok

Comment: May be you have shape keys.